# array and pointer relationship,why this code not prints a[i]

Tags: c

i have tried a c program on array and pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10], i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
    fun(a,i);
}

fun(int *p, int i)
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", &*(p+i));
    }
}
```

output is:

```
2752228
2752232
2752236
2752240
2752244
2752248
2752252
2752256
2752260
2752264
```

it prints addresses instead of array elements

Comment: Remove the `&`. Dunno why you are passing `i` to `fun` though...

Comment: You print addresses instead of values. *p is the value, &(*p) is the address

Comment: Tip: [Suggested reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/589924)

Comment: BTW, `fun` has no prototype. It should throw some warnings

Comment: What Eugene Sh. means is that `fun` is called before it's declared. That's a problem. Either change the order of your functions, or add `void fun(int *p, int i);` near the top to declare `fun` before it's defined.

Comment: For start, turn on all warnings and make the compiler report them as errors. [This is what the compiler would tell you then](https://godbolt.org/g/ZGYDt2): 1) implicit declaration of function `fun` (**no prototype for `fun`**), 2) `fun` return type defaults to `int` (**you forgot `void` at the beginning**), 3) format `%d` expects argument of type `int`, but argument 2 has type `int *` (**you are passing a pointer instead of a number**), 4) control reaches end of non-void function (**compiler thinks `fun` should return `int`**).

Comment: `&` and `*` are opposite operators. `&*p == p` and `*&p == p` as well

Comment: print isn typesafe. If You are not sure, what it is type, use itermedaite variable. Compiler give kind of warning

Answer (score 5):

`*` and `&` together here nullify each other's effect.  `&*(p+i)` is equivalent to `(p+i)`. `(p+i)` gives the address of the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the array. To access the element's value you need to remove `&` from that expression, which will be `*(p+i)` and is equivalent to `p[i]`.

---

**Note:** Instead of using a loop to initialize all elements of an array you can use initializer list as follows

```
int a[10] = {0};
```

Also you have to pass size of the array to the function. Your function should use that size to know the length of the array passed.

```
fun(int *p, int size){
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add a function prototype before `main`

```
void fun(int *p, int size);
```

and call it

```
fun(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`&*x` side by side applied results in `x` and here that `x` is `p+i`. `p` is the pointer to the first element of the array and added `i` to it, the value is incremented by `sizeof *p` here `sizeof int` which is 4 bytes in your case. More clearly you printed `&p[i]` in each iteration and that too with wrong format specifier. Use `%p` format specifier for printing address.

If you want to print the array - remove the address of operator `&` and instead use the value that you want to print `*(p+i)` or `p[i]`.

You have passed `i` though not clear why. You have used hard-coded value for array length. Know that if your intention was to pass the size of the array you could pass `sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]` - this term is nothing but the size of the array.